# How can I update a map inside a big entity class?

Tags: java, jpa, dictionary, entity

I have this situation

```
public void add(Integer key,Integer val) {
    EntityManager em = ...;
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    BigEntity be = em.find(BigEntity.class,beId); // I want avoid this
    be.getMap().put(key,val);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

How can I update the map without getting the entire BigEntity?
I cant wrap the map, thanks in advance